# Mule ESB pluggability

Tags: mule, esb

I am new to Mule ESB. I want to know that, can I upgrade Mule application without redeploying. I am talking about pluggability. Suppose my application is already running and now some more features or client flow added. Now I want to add this new flow like a new plugin. Is it possible to do it without down time.?
For e.g. In my Mule application, I have used one HTTP connector to connect with one client.
Now in case of new HTTP connector required to add, can I do it without redeploy.?

Answer (score 1):

You can now modify your configuration files and custom classes and have them reloaded without having to restart Mule.

Mule checks every three seconds for updated configuration files under the $MULE_HOME/apps directory, and when it finds one, it reloads the configuration file and the JARs in that applications lib directory.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.2/hot-deployment

Answer (score 1):

You can "try" to update or replace an application folder contents and touch/modify the application’s configuration file to have Mule reload the config and automatically re-deploy the application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. What you can do is to deploy a new application, and use the same HTTP connector if you define it in a common domain for both applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in a single server. You can achieve it through martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html .
 To make this work you need two servers and a proxy in front. You take one server offline in the proxy, update it then reenable. Then you do the same with the second server. we are facing same issue in Talend ESB.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible but you can add and redeploy the application